# R version 3.3.3 for MacOS Mojave vesion 10.14.6, which R-studio to download?

Tags: r, rstudio, version

I am trying to work out which version of R-studio is available for R 3.3.3 running on Mac Mojave OS 10.14.6, I went to the website and as this is my first time downloading R and R studio it does not seem immediately apparent to me.

Please help!

My thanks,

R downloaded, went to r-studio, not clear which option is best

Comment: I recommend downloading the most recent compatible version of R which should be 4.2.3. Try this link: cran.r-project.org/bin/macosx/base/R-4.2.3.pkg and Version 2022.07 of Rstudio should work https://dailies.rstudio.com/version/2022.07.2+576.pro12/

Comment: Is there a specific reason that you can't update R?